# Can I load data from a file on the server side?

Tags: server, webclient

Hi,

my server structure is like this

```
/server
/www
```

/www directory is accessible on the internet and /server is not. But I have a xml file inside /server I need to open from a js file inside /www in order to get data from. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Maybe with the right security. The js would have to make a call to the server...

Comment: could you please tell me how?

Comment: Heyyy!! what about some help??? HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEELP!!